# how can I use cscope under windows gvim perfectly

Tags: windows, vim, cscope

Here's my question, I'm trying to use gvim under windows, and I am using cscope to walk through my code, but, when I init the cscope database under vim, there's always a problem.

my code's root folder is: D:\MyCode

and there are many subfolders, cscope.out's path is :D:\MyCode\cscope.out.

I wrote these lines when vim start:

```
:cs add D:\MyCode\cscope.out D:\MyCode
```

but the connection won't be established, so how can I define a pre-path under windows gvim?

if I use `:cs add D:\MyCode\cscope.out` it will work, but then I can't find the code under other subfolders.

please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write a `gvim.bat` batch file that changes directory to `D:\MyCode\` before starting `gvim`, will the simpler command work?

Incidentally, under Linux and `vim`, I always use `:cs add .` to add the `cscope` database and connection from the current working directory.